# Access is denied in search service application in SharePoint 2010

Tags: search

We have done migration from Sharepoint 2007 to 2010, configured its Search Service.

After that the Search service found default web application setting that was created in first step of 2010 installation and this will work for default web application service only and for next web applications that we created and added to the content source ->Type start addresses below field, we will receive this error:

> Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access
>   Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl
>   this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint
>   repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read"
>   permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled

And in addition, my user has full permission in SQL and sharepoint farm.